# React Native Problem with tabBarIcon - createElement : type is invalid

Tags: reactjs

Im new to RN.  currently teaching myself the react navigation.  Im using a MaterialBottomTabNavigator nested inside a StackNavigator.  I am trying to incorporate icons into my bottom tab but getting an error: "Invariant Violation... check the render method of : BottomNavigation"

Have spent hours trying to solve this but don't know enough to get myself out of this problem - hoping someone can help..

Here's is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Camera from './camera'
import VideoComponent from './video'
import AudioComponent from './audio'
import File from './file'
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';


const CaptureNav = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();


class Capture extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <CaptureNav.Navigator >

        <CaptureNav.Screen 
          name="Camera" 
          component= {Camera}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon : () => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name='camera' color={'black'} size={26} />
            )
          }}
        />

        <CaptureNav.Screen 
          name="Video" 
          component= {VideoComponent} 

        />

        <CaptureNav.Screen 
          name="Audio" 
          component= {AudioComponent}

        />

         <CaptureNav.Screen 
          name="File" 
          component= {File} 

        />

      </CaptureNav.Navigator>
    )
  }
}

export default Capture
```

Here is the error :

Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `BottomNavigation`.

This error is located at:

```
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at BottomNavigation.tsx:838)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at BottomNavigation.tsx:832)
    in RCTView (at BottomNavigation.tsx:831)
    in RCTView (at BottomNavigation.tsx:272)
    in TouchableWithoutFeedback (at BottomNavigation.tsx:271)
    in Unknown (at BottomNavigation.tsx:815)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at react-native-safe-area-view/index.js:163)
    in SafeView (at withOrientation.js:54)
    in withOrientation (at BottomNavigation.tsx:741)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at BottomNavigation.tsx:740)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Surface.tsx:70)
    in Surface (created by Context.Consumer)
    in ThemedComponent (created by withTheme(Surface))
    in withTheme(Surface) (at BottomNavigation.tsx:708)
    in RCTView (at BottomNavigation.tsx:665)
    in BottomNavigation (created by Context.Consumer)
    in ThemedComponent (created by withTheme(BottomNavigation))
    in withTheme(BottomNavigation) (at MaterialBottomTabView.tsx:48)
    in MaterialBottomTabView (at createMaterialBottomTabNavigator.tsx:42)
    in MaterialBottomTabNavigator (at capture.js:16)
    in Capture (at SceneView.tsx:98)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:89)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:88)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:125)
    in RCTView (at BottomTabView.tsx:38)
    in SceneContent (at BottomTabView.tsx:122)
    in RCTView (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:37)
    in RCTView (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:26)
    in ResourceSavingScene (at BottomTabView.tsx:117)
    in RCTView (at screens.native.js:132)
    in ScreenContainer (at BottomTabView.tsx:101)
    in RCTView (at BottomTabView.tsx:100)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at BottomTabView.tsx:99)
    in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:41)
    in BottomTabNavigator (at homescr.js:14)
    in HomeScreen (at SceneView.tsx:98)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:89)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:88)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:125)
    in RCTView (at CardContainer.tsx:187)
    in RCTView (at CardContainer.tsx:186)
    in RCTView (at Card.tsx:508)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Card.tsx:491)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:484)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Card.tsx:480)
    in RCTView (at Card.tsx:473)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:154)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:518)
    in RCTView (at CardStack.tsx:109)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:511)
    in RCTView (at CardStack.tsx:92)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:410)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:384)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:382)
    in RNCSafeAreaView (at src/index.tsx:28)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:379)
    in RCTView (at StackView.tsx:378)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:67)
    in StackNavigator (at App.js:19)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:267)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:39)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:38)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:18)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:101)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

renderRoot
    [native code]:0
runRootCallback
    [native code]:0
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    [native code]:0
```

Comment: use import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

Comment: Thank you Ashwith, that did solve the problem but another has emerged - "Unrecognized Font Family - 'Material Icons'. I'll mark this as answered though an start trying to solve this new font issue. Thanks again

Comment: are u getting error in ios or android